# Why would my firewall show that my computer connects to DNS servers other than the ones I have defined?

Tags: dns

I'm looking at my firewall logs and even though I have my computer set to a static DNS, the logs are showing that my computer is reaching out to multiple DNS servers via port 53.  I am worried about botnet activity.

Comment: Not all legitimate services on your machine use the DNS servers you configure in your network settings. Some have hardcoded DNS settings. What DNS servers are being queried?

Comment: It would be better for you to monitor the connections on your computer to see what is making them. Nothing says that an application must stick to only the defined DNS servers for the computer.

Comment: There's very little to go on here.  First, what are you looking for? Confirmation that you have malware? Advice on how to tell if you have malware? Possible explanations for why there might be legitimate services that ignore the OS settings?

Comment: just random DNS root server, I have added the ones in MSoft/Google ranges

Comment: Since anything can make requests to a non-system specified DNS server, you have no way to know if it's good or bad software making the request. The only way to know is to monitor the processes on your computer to find which one(s) is making the request and judge if that process is good or bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your firewall logs requests to DNS servers other than those defined in the OS because an application is making requests to its own configured alternative DNS servers. Google Chrome, for instance will make requests to 8.8.8.8 despite your OS configuration.

You can verify this with tools like Fiddler or similar. If these requests are a problem for you, block them at your local system or network router/firewall.

Incidentally, monitoring DNS requests on a network is an effective detection practice for this reason.